# Do I need to re download Blender?

Tags: versions

I currently have the Blender 2.80 release candidate, and now that the official 2.80 is out, I was wondering if I need to download it again to stay up to date or if the release candidate is the same as the current 2.80.

Comment: I've come across a couple of bugs in the candidate which have been ironed out in the release, myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender RC 3 and the official release of Blender 2.8 are not the same version. The last release candidate is a build based on commit [507ffee6e1f4](https://developer.blender.org/rB507ffee6e1f4a2b2795c7c93cd3f37f4df748ee9) and the release version is based on commit [f6cb5f54494e](https://developer.blender.org/rBf6cb5f54494e40f0d217c7a1520a14896bd19120). That means there have been additional fixes between the release candidate and the final release.

In general it's best to update from official release to official release, unless you really need the cutting edge version. If you want to use experimental builds, be aware that bugs, compatibility issues and broken projects may happen.

Comment: One could say this is always the case for the overnight build. (Which currently is at 2.81) For most users I wouldn't necessarily  recommend downloading it every day.  Candidates are put forward for release. A release is a release. Suggest downloading an official release.

Comment: @batFINGER Yes I agree, the official release is what should be used. I just answered the question whether RC3 and the release where the same version which in theory they could have been. They even have the same version number (2.80.75), but they are not identical.

Comment: Sure if basing build vs build equality on commit #.. Hypothetically all commits between last RC and release could be "cosmetic" code cleanup and the like and in no way alter functionality.  Yes, Use the official release, is IMO the best  answer to question title,  For most users there is no need to stay "up to date", any further than the latest official release was the point of comment above.

Comment: ... sorry re confusion, the comment is for here, in case someone apon finding the [buildbot download page](https://builder.blender.org/download/), wonders if they need to download "to stay up to date".  anyhoo latest edit got it.

Comment: @batFINGER sure a warning about using these builds is definitely warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to download a new version every time as there's no update option built into Blender. Hence, it's best to download a zip version e.g. for testing or wait a while. As to me, I wait for 2.81.